# Transpose column names to rows and put values in seperate column

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have the following table which you can also find in the `SQL fiddle` [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0e8807/2):

```
CREATE TABLE Flows (
    Product TEXT,
    Inbound_Date DATE,
    Outbound_Date DATE,
    Return_Date DATE,
    Quantity VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO Flows
(Product, Inbound_Date, Outbound_Date, Return_Date, Quantity)
VALUES 

("Product A", "2019-01-01", NULL, NULL, "400"),
("Product A", NULL, "2019-05-08", NULL, "200"),
("Product A", NULL, NULL, "2019-06-25", "600"),

("Product B", "2019-03-08", NULL, NULL, "380"),
("Product B", NULL, "2019-03-15", NULL, "120"),
("Product B", NULL, NULL, "2019-04-17", "610");
```

I use the following SQL to get the values from the table:

```
SELECT Product, Inbound_Date, Outbound_Date, Return_Date, sum(Quantity)
FROM Flows
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4;
```

All this works fine so far.

---

However, now I want to achieve that the dates are displayed in one column called `FLow_Date`. 
The result should look like this:

```
Product          Date_Type            Flow_Date
Product A        Inbound_Date        2019-01-01
Product A        Oubound_Date        2019-05-08
Product A        Return_Date         2019-06-25
Product B        Inbound_Date        2019-03-08
Product B        Outbound_Date       2019-03-15
Product B        Return_Date         2019-04-17
```

What do I need to change in my code to make it work?

Comment: . . Can you have multiple non-`NULL` values per row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need `case` expressions:

```
select f.product,
       (case when inbound_date is not null then 'inbound_date' 
             when outbound_date is not null then 'outbound_date'
             when return_date is not null then 'return_date'
        end) date_type,
       (case when inbound_date is not null then inbound_date
             when outbound_date is not null then outbound_date
             when return_date is not null then return_date
        end) as flow_date
from flows f;
```

This becomes more complicated if you can have multiple non-`NULL` values per row.

In that case, `union all` is a simple enough approach

```
select fd.*
from ((select f.product, 'inbound_date' as date_type, inbound_date as flow_date
       from flows f
      ) union all
      (select f.product, 'outbound_date' as date_type, outbound_date as flow_date
       from flows f
      ) union all
      (select f.product, 'return_date' as date_type, return_date as flow_date
       from flows f
      )
     ) fd
where flow_date is not null;
```

This is not necessarily the most efficient method (in this case), but it works well.  If `flows` is really a view, then alternatives might be preferred.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I needed. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0e8807/7

Answer (score 0):

you can use `coalesce()` and a `case` expression:

```
select
    product,
    case 
        when inbound_date is null  then 'inbound_date' 
        when outbound_date is null then 'outbound_date'
        when return_date is null   then 'return_date'
    end date_type,
    coalesce(inbound_date, outbound_date, return_date) flow_date
from mytable
```

Of if you want this in your aggregate query:

```
select
    product,
    case 
        when inbound_date is null  then 'inbound_date' 
        when outbound_date is null then 'outbound_date'
        when return_date is null   then 'return_date'
    end date_type,
    coalesce(inbound_date, outbound_date, return_date) flow_date,
    sum(quantity) sum_quantity
from mytable
group by 
    product,
    date_type,
    flow_date
```