# Transpose columns to rows in query if table contains NULL values

Tags: mysql, sql

**[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=8a8db642a713c9cdd2a38e4a32c5f761)**

```
CREATE TABLE logistics (
    id int primary key,
    campaign VARCHAR(255),
    inbound_date VARCHAR(255),
    outbound_date VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO logistics
(id, campaign, inbound_date, outbound_date)
VALUES 
("1", "C001", "2019-01-01", "2019-02-08"),
("2", "C001", "2019-05-10", "2019-05-12"),
("3", "C001", "2019-06-12", NULL),
("4", "C001", NULL, "2019-06-15"),
("5", "C002", "2019-11-14", "2019-11-22"),
("6", "C002", NULL, "2019-12-13"),
("7", "C002", NULL, NULL);
```

In the table above I have the columns `inbound_date` and `outbound_date`. 
Now, I want to transpose them to one `column` called `event_type`.

**Expected Result**

```
Campaign     event_type          event_date
C001         inbound_date        2019-01-01
C001         outbound_date       2019-02-08
C001         inbound_date        2019-05-10
C001         outbound_date       2019-05-12
C001         inbound_date        2019-06-12
C001         outbound_date       2019-06-15
C002         inbound_date        2019-11-14
C002         outbound_date       2019-11-22
C002         outbound_date       2019-12-13
```

---

First, I tried to go with the solution form [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60265007/transpose-column-names-to-rows-and-put-values-in-seperate-column):

```
select campaign,
       (case when inbound_date is not null then 'inbound_date' 
             when outbound_date is not null then 'outbound_date'
        end) event_date,
       (case when inbound_date is not null then inbound_date
             when outbound_date is not null then outbound_date
        end) as event_date
from logistics;
```

Second, I tried it with the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60489903/using-alias-from-coalesce-from-select-in-where-clause):

```
SELECT campaign,
       coalesce(inbound_date, outbound_date) as event_date
FROM logistics;
```

With both queries I do not get any result. 
I assume the issue is somehow the `NULL` values in the table. 
How can I get the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select campaign, 'inbound_date' as event_type,  inbound_date as event_date
from logistics
where inbound_date is not null
union all
select campaign, 'outbound_date' as event_type,  outbound_date as event_date
from logistics
where outbound_date is not null;
```